# Simple form: translate radio as select Yes/No

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

```
<%=f.input_field :radio, as: :select, class: "form-control chosen-select"%>
```

I have to translate it into "Si/No".

I have tried this, but nothing happens.

**simple_form.it.yml**

```
it:
  simple_form:
    "yes": "Si"
    "no" : "No"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change in your **application.rb**

`config.i18n.default_locale = :it`

Then in `config/locales` create a **it.yml** and a **simple_form.it.yml** file

Edit your template file  :

`<%= f.input :radio, as: :select, include_blank: false, class: "form-control chosen-select" %>`

Restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found is to use collection:

```
<%= f.input :radio, as: :select, include_blank: false, collection: ['si','no'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with `collection: [['si', true],['no', false]]`

Make sure you use true and false, and not 1, or 0 otherwise the radio buttons won't pick up on the models value in an edit view

Answer (score 0):

@AntoineWattier answer works. 
Make sure that the app server is really restarted after changing the translations, as SimpleForm caches the boolean translations internally:

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/inputs/collection_input.rb#L12

Maybe try also cleaning out all caches: `rake tmp:clear`.